# Automatic conversion of GWT web app to Mobile App

Tags: mobile, gwt, smartgwt, mgwt

Is there any tool to convert automatically the existing gwt web application to mobile gwt using mgwt or smartgwt.mobile or any other mobile gwt widgets with out any effort?
for example we can add mgwt in the classpath and swap the widgets, can we avoid the above steps by any way a tool automatically take care of conversion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no tool that allows such conversion.

I think you should consider several important factors.

First, most apps need at least some changes when adjusted to smartphone screens compared to desktop versions. While you can re-use a lot of code, if your app is architected properly, many if not all views may need to change. In some cases you may realize that required changes are significant (e.g. a tree on the left side with a DataGrid on the right side won't work on a smartphone screen).

Second, MGWT uses a different layout model. There is no equivalent to LayoutPanel, VerticalPanel, DockLayoutPanel, etc. - all of these layouts are achieved through flex-box layout model, which is fundamentally different.

NB: If you think that you app already looks and works correctly on small screens, there is probably no need to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Yes, I understood your points to consider during conversion. I think even gwt app already works on small screen, still we need to convert using smargwt.mobile or mgwt so that we can make app native usign PhoneGap, Am I right? Please let me know any other framework to covert gwt to mobile other than mgwt?

Comment: You don't need MGWT to create a PhoneGap project. You can use your existing GWT project.

Comment: Thank you. For application not supporting mobile screen what are all the option we have to convert the view part other than below pls? mgwt, smartgwt.mobile and which one is best?

Comment: It depends on your project. I try to stay with pure GWT, and only use a few MGWT widgets like a ScrollPanel (which is different from GWT ScrollPanel), but my GWT projects already use flex-box layout model.